# When flex column wraps, how can I make the second column not take up the full height of the first column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Let's say I have a flex container with 15 items. If I want the column to wrap so that 10 items are in the first column (for example) and 5 are in the second column, each item in the second column should only take up the same height as the ones in the first column. In other words, the 5 items shouldn't take up the same amount of space as the first column -- the spacing just looks weird.

Is there a way to make it so that the last item in the list only shows up at the halfway point of the height of the overall container?

What I'd like:

```
Item      Item 
Item      Item
Item      Item
Item      Item 
Item      Item
Item      
Item       
Item      
Item
```

What is happening:

```
Item      Item 
Item      
Item      Item
Item       
Item      Item
Item      
Item      Item 
Item      
Item      Item
```

React / styled-components code:

```
  <DailyValuesContainer flexDirection="column" wrap="wrap" justify="space-between">
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>0g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Saturated Fat</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>0g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Trans Fat</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>0mg</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Cholesterol</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>7mg</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Sodium</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>11g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Dietary Fibers</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>8g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Sugar</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>1%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Vitamin A</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>4%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Vitamin C</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>11%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Calcium</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
      <DailyValueItem>
        <DvQuantity>34%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Iron</DailyValue>
      </DailyValueItem>
    </DailyValuesContainer>
```

```
 const DailyValuesContainer = styled(FlexContainer)`
  max-height: 170px;

const DailyValueItem = styled(FlexContainer)`
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 12px;
`

const DailyValue = styled.p`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: ${colors.primary500};
`
const DvQuantity = styled(DailyValue)`
  width: 45px;
`
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with your code?

Comment: If you are interested, this is a lot easier to achieve via grid: https://jsfiddle.net/51anytxj/

Comment: You told the app to add space between the item with `justify="space-between"`. Simply remove it.

Comment: Yep that was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are u expecting like this :

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#main div {
  width: inherit;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:grey;">item 1 </div>

  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">item 2 </div>

  <div style="background-color:khaki;">item 3 </div>

  <div style="background-color:pink;">item 4 </div>

  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">item 5</div>

  <div style="background-color:grey;">item 6 </div>

  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">item 7 </div>

  <div style="background-color:khaki;">item 8</div>

  <div style="background-color:pink;">item 9</div>

  <div style="background-color:red;">item 10</div>


  <div style="background-color:grey;">item 1 </div>

  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">item 2 </div>

  <div style="background-color:khaki;">item 3 </div>

  <div style="background-color:pink;">item 4 </div>

  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Try this code:

```
<DailyValuesContainer>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>0g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Saturated Fat</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>0g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Trans Fat</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>0mg</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Cholesterol</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>7mg</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Sodium</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>11g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Dietary Fibers</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>8g</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Sugar</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>1%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Vitamin A</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>4%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Vitamin C</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>11%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Calcium</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
    <DailyValueItem>
      <DvQuantity>34%</DvQuantity><DailyValue>Iron</DailyValue>
    </DailyValueItem>
</DailyValuesContainer>


const DailyValuesContainer = styled(FlexContainer)'
width: 200px;
height: 600px;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
 ';    

const DailyValueItem = styled(FlexContainer)'
width: inherit;
height: 60px;
';    

const DailyValue = styled.p'
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 15px;
color: ${colors.primary500};
';

const DvQuantity = styled(DailyValue)'
width: 45px;
';
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that's not what is happening, even though I have the same basic setup. I am now adding the React code I'm using if that helps.

Comment: upload your code in  codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) and share the link @ipenguin67

Comment: first remove justify="space-between" , copy all the css property of the #main   set to <DailyValuesContainer> and  copy all the  css property of the #main div  and set to <DailyValueItem>  .   According to u r code #main ---> <DailyValuesContainer , #main div ---------> <DailyValueItem>  @ipenguin67

Comment: Ah yeah, the justify-content definitely was causing this one -- I had added it to try to get space between the columns but forgot it was handling the vertical spacing since the flex-direction was "column". Definitely a mindless mistake.